# HTTP proxy server behind a GCP load balancer with basic authentication

Tags: proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to run an HTTP(S) proxy service in a GKE cluster, and take advantage of the existing Kubernetes ingress and the GCP load balancer to provide TLS termination and a stable public IP for the service. The clients would access the proxy via the public internet using basic auth.

So far I've run into three issues:

1. It's tricky to configure an HTTP health check for the proxy, because the health check can only be configured with a relative path (e.g. `GET /`) and the proxy only responds to requests for fully qualified URLs (e.g. `GET http://www.example.com). **I was able to work around this by modifying the (open source) proxy server implementation to add a health check at a relative URL.**
2. Similarly, the URL map requires a relative path, beginning with a '/'. **I was able to work around this by specifying the proxy service as the default backend for the ingress**, which is used if none of the host/path rules match.
3. Here's where I'm stuck. **The load balancer appears to strip the `Proxy-Authorization` header** sent by the client. So when the requests arrive at the proxy server, they are missing the auth header, and fail with a `407 Proxy Authentication Required`.

It's obviously not an option to disable authentication on the proxy. I haven't found any documentation acknowledging that the load balancer strips this header, or why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use this type of balancer for something it isn't designed to do.  GCP HTTP load balancers are reverse HTTP proxies -- they don't front-end for forward proxies.  What you have working so far is essentially working by accident.

I'd suggest that your application actually needs a [TCP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/) rather than HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes HTTP(S) load balancer by default works with 4. But you can create a "User-defined request header".
Please take a look to  [link1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/)   and  [link2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#user-defined-request-headers)

Comment: It looks like user-defined request headers need to have a static value configured in the load balancer, so they couldn't be used for authentication. Or is there some way to define a header whose value is passed-through from the client request?